# no POST while booting. monitor not displaying anything

Tags: memory, display, motherboard, power-supply, post

The monitor not displaying anything.
I don't hear the POST signal as well. ( the beep while booting )

Things that I have tried.

- Connected MONITOR to laptop ( which I am using currently ), displaying properly working fine. So, it is not the Monitor's fault.
- Connected keyboard USB to desktop while booting ( it is detecting keyboard, I can switch numlock off/on )
- Cleared CMOS by touching two pins ( reading the motherboard manual Gigabyte that I got from shipment )
- Switched RAM's, placing them in different slots and placing only one RAM instead of both. Purchased another ( better RAM ) Kingston DDR3 ( saw the mobo manual and checked if it supports ).
- Removed the RADEON HD 6870 Graphics card from its slot and put it back again to make sure it fit perfectly.
- Also, removed DVD drive, because I don't need it now.
- Also, removed all the USB drives ( no keyboard, no mouse ).
- I have also tried removing all the RAM(s), and booted the system. It is turned on for some time ( around 6 seconds ) and turn off automatically, and then turn on again. It happened 3 times, So, I turned it off. I made sure, the speakers are on all the time, no beep/weird noise heard. ( Recommendation attempt from Luke )
- replaced PSU with the one that I borrowed from my friend, it still doesn't give any beeps while booting. monitor still not displaying anything. Now, I am guessing the motherboard/processor is at fault.

Nothing helped.

I see that the fan-supply that is connected to the processor is spinning and the fan on the RADEON is also spinning.

I don't hear any weird beeps/noises while booting.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the power supply is next. If you don't have another one, and you're sure the speaker is connected (for the POST beeps), remove all the RAM and see if 3 beeps are sounded.

Just out of curiosity, is this a new build or a computer that suddenly stopped working?

Comment: I got this computer from a company( ibuypower ) today. I thought of building it myself, but got lazy and didn't do it. got served I think. PSU is from some company I have never heard of, so I want to replace it with a new one ( good company ) hopefully, it will fix it. I don't want to send it back ( shipping costs me extra )

Comment: Never heard of that company... Hopefully it does get fixed with a new PSU, but I would also then send them the bill for fixing it

Comment: replaced PSU with the one that I borrowed from my friend, it still doesn't give any beeps while booting. monitor still not displaying anything. Now, I am guessing the motherboard/processor is at fault.

Comment: I hope I can get a complete refund on this junk.

Comment: @anon_anon I hope you can too

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the on-board video, also try to remove the battery on the mobo (make sure the computer is not plugged in) then after a few minutes press the power button a couple of times just to make sure that no power is sitting in the mobo, then put battery back in and then plug in the computer